# How to track if element is visible on screen with same class when scrolling with jquery

Tags: jquery, scroll

I have products listed under each other(each product has the same class productItem) by one and wanna create the following

When user scrolls to the product and when one product starts to be visible i need to display that current visible product some info on the bottom with fixed position like price, title, link etc.

I have tried the following code but it did not work cause my elements are with the same class

```
$.fn.isOnScreen = function(){
        var win = $(window);
        var viewport = {
            top : win.scrollTop(),
            left : win.scrollLeft()
        };
        viewport.right = viewport.left + win.width();
        viewport.bottom = viewport.top + win.height();

        var bounds = this.offset();
        bounds.right = bounds.left + this.outerWidth();
        bounds.bottom = bounds.top + this.outerHeight();
        return (!(viewport.right < bounds.left || viewport.left > bounds.right || viewport.bottom < bounds.top || viewport.top > bounds.bottom));
    };
    jQuery(document).scroll(function(){
        alert(jQuery('.productItem').isOnScreen());
    });
```

Any idea how i can fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to apply your function to each elements. `$('.productItem').each(function(){ $(this).isOnScreen() });` and you should use the console to debug it, not `alerts` ;)

Comment: Yeah it works @TCHdvlp perfectly with each. Only one issue. Am displaying the current visible element info within the fixed position div. So when i scroll the current visible element is being displayed early. am i clear?

Comment: You should add the height of the fixed div to make your condition match. Like `viewport.bottom + fixedHeight < bounds.top`

Comment: it did not help. i edited viewport.bottom and added -fixedheight @TCHdvlp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to apply your function to each elements ?
And, you should use the console to debug it, not alerts ;)

```
$('.productItem').each(function(){ 
    console.log($(this).isOnScreen());
});
```

Comment: There is one issue when scrolling up. It continue to show the first element info. Any idea how i can fix this @TCHdvlp ? Thanks

Comment: Something like a test. Is there a productItem on Screen ? If not, erase the fixed content.

Comment: Sorry @TCHdvlp can you detail? what i need to check? how?

Comment: when am scrolling up productitem is not visible for some height screen but it still shows the content from current visible item

Comment: We should conitnue this discussion in a chat or something

Comment: Ok let me know how @TCHdvlp?

Comment: I have the same issue when am reaching to footer. I still see current last product info. Is there a way to solve this pls @TCHdvlp?

Comment: Oo, seems that chat features aren't allowed anymore. Anyway, To solve your problem you must implement an 'erase' or 'cleanup' logic. As long as a product is visible, display its info. If no product is visible on screen, clean the fixed details.

Comment: I understand that, the issue is that am using each so it did not check for only one product, it is checking for all.

Comment: Also is there a way to track when the scroll passes to next product so i can do someaction when passing to next product. Any idea?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114129/discussion-between-anahit-dev-and-tchdvlp).